# python 2 / list / if statements / user inputs

Tags: python-2.x

```
European_countries = ['Germany' , 'France' , 'United Kingdom' , 'Italy' , 'Spain' , 'Switzerland' , 'Netherlands' , 'Greece' , 'Poland' , 'Ukraine' , 'Austria' , 'Belgium' , 'Sweden' , 'Croatia' , 'Norway' , 'Iceland' , 'Romania' , 'Denmark' , 'Malta' , 'Czech Rebublic' , 'Republic of Ireland' , 'Hungary' , 'Finland' , 'Bulgaria' , 'Cyprus' , 'Luxembourg' , 'Serbia' , 'Albania' , 'Slovenia' , 'Lithuania' , 'Montenegro' , 'Slovakia' , 'Estonia' , 'Latvia' , 'Macendonia' , 'Belarus' , 'Monaca' , 'Vatican City' , 'Moldova' , 'Bosnia and Herzegovia' , 'Gibraltar' , 'Andorra' , 'Liechtenstein' , 'Faroe Islands' , 'San Marino' , 'Isle of Man' , 'Aland Islands' , 'Guernsey' , 'Kingdom of the Netherlands' , 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen']

user = input('what is a European country. be exact ')

if user == European_countries [0:39]:

  print('yes')

else:

  print('nope')
```

When I do input one of the things from the list in console, it always goes to the else statement. It never works for the print yes.

Thank you for the help, I'm doing small projects in class and need this help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to test if user is in `European_countries`. In python, you can do that like this

```
if user in European_countries:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('nope')
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot all about some things since we started using a different program.